# How to change the default login button to redirect to the custom page

Tags: customer-community, login-errors

The default login button in community leads to a blank page. How do I change the url where that button should redirect to? Can't find the option anywhere.

Thanks

Comment: Have you checked the Administration > Login and Registration page for the community?

Comment: Yes I did. Couldn't figure out

Comment: I can access the login page in community builder. But how do I add a redirect option? Is there a way I can drag some component from community builder that could redirect the page. I guess my concern is how to add some logic in community builder page?

Answer (score 0):

The [Customize Your Community’s Login Experience](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=networks_customize_login_page.htm&type=5) help explains how to point to a different login page.

> From Setup, enter All Communities in the Quick Find box, then click
>   All Communities. Click Workspaces next to the name of your community.
>
> Select Administration, then select Login & Registration, and make your
>   changes under the Login section.
>
> Optionally, choose a custom login page for your community. Select the
>   page type, Community Builder or Visualforce. Then enter the name of
>   the page in the search field, and click Lookup search icon for custom
>   login page. In the search results window, click the name of the page
>   to select it.

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the help. Is there any default login page that I can use? The default login page is blank. I would prefer not to create any custom page if there is already any with  UI and the functionality.

Comment: The default login page should not be blank.  You should open a case with Salesforce support to determine why it is blank.

Comment: I replaced the login Type to "Default Page" and it worked :) Thanks a bunch!!